# erro 150 when restore backup with php script

Tags: mysql

I use [this script](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php) for mysql backup (with changes -- add "continue" after chekching `$result` if it is empty -- it means that when a table has no data skip it- nothing important)

But when I restore I got this error(it seems that when backup the forms.grab_fields didnt backup)

> #1005 - Can't create table 'forms.grab_fields' (errno: 150)

But when I backup with phpMyAdmin it works

And I use Myisam engine (I changed to innodb but no changes)

Comment: The question's title and the actual question don't quite correlate... Anything else to share?

Comment: excuse me,i got confused

Comment: Does it work if you use the original scipt without modifications?